# Get View when using fragments

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the `View` of the layout. I need to create button listeners and such but I have no idea how to do that. I'm using `ViewPager` to host the tabs with layout fragments.

Here's the code I'm currently using

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonOpenDialog;
    private Button buttonUp;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        View nice = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(0).getView();

        buttonOpenDialog = (Button) nice.findViewById(R.id.opendialog);
        buttonOpenDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        senddata = (Button) nice.findViewById(R.id.send);
        senddata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int sectionNum = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            View rootView = (sectionNum == 1 ? inflater.inflate(R.layout.sendfragment, container, false) : inflater.inflate(R.layout.receivefragment, container, false));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Send";
                case 1:
                    return "Receive";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?, you have set up fragments in viewPager, have you created individual two fragments for two tabs?

Comment: Are you trying to create the button listeners from your fragment? If so you should add that code in the `onCreateView` method of the fragment. You can do `rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewId)`

Comment: @Dankrushen Not sure I understand the comment entirely but after taking a closer look at your code I notice some problems. First do not keep a static reference to your MainActivity as you are likely going to cause a memory leak and other problems by doing so. Second, I noticed you are retrieving your fragment's UI components from within the `onCreate` method of the `Activity` hosting it. All your UI logic for the fragment should be done within the fragment itself.

Comment: @AjayP.Prajapati I have created one fragment, which hosts two layouts.

Answer (score 0):

To get view from fragment, you can use:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.abc);
```

To understand where in a fragment you can do this, study the fragment lifecycle - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: or findViewById(R.id.abc)